# How to style a vector layer in QGIS using hexadecimal color code stored in attribute?

Tags: qgis, qgis-2, style, fields-attributes

I have a polygon shapefile storing hexadecimal color codes in a specific attribute.

```
  gid    |   label   |   color
---------+-----------+------------
1        | Crops     | #FF5F2C
2        | Forest    | #00FF00
3        | Pond      | #0000FF
4        | Forest    | #00FF00
```

I was looking for a way to say QGIS to read these values in order to style the polygons with them. I can't find anything about this.

I hoped it would be possible without deeping into the Python Console (which still frightens me...).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In Layer Properties make a click on "Simple Fill" (in the left part). On the right side click the symbol for data defined color and choose Field type: string > color (field in the attribute table).

[image]

It works in QGIS 2.8.2. But I'm missing the different colors for this layer "buffer" in the map legend.
[image]

Comment: There is no connection between coors and attributes, so ... no legend possible. See also https://hub.qgis.org/issues/11491.

Comment: Good! Many thanks... It works perfectly. The legend issue has to be kept in mind, depending on the necessity to produce a map or not.

Comment: @HanneK, that link from 2015 is broken. Here is a link of the last working snapshot: http://web.archive.org/web/20161004235323/http://hub.qgis.org/issues/11491