# Showing legend with categories using a hexadecimal color scheme

Tags: symbology, style, color

I have a polyline vector layer with in one column the route number (of the bus) and in another the hexadecimal color (eg 'FF88AA'). Preview:

[image]

I know how to style the file but only by using the single symbology, found here:
[How to style a vector layer in QGIS using hexadecimal color code stored in attribute?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/155395/how-to-style-a-vector-layer-in-qgis-using-hexadecimal-color-code-stored-in-attri)

Is there a way by using 'categories' or something as I need a legend with the route number and the matching color. Is this possible in QGIS?

Comment: Do you use/ have access to QGIS or also other software? Or do you want to only use QGIS?

Comment: Hi, yes preferably i want to use QGIS to do this. If not possible perhaps via office excel?